# How to allow Joi.number() to accept decimal numbers with both dot and comma as separators?

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, schema, joi

I'm using `Joi` for validation in my Node.js application, and I have a field that should accept decimal numbers with both dot and comma as separators. However, when I use `Joi.number()`, it only accepts numbers with a dot as the decimal separator.

Here's an example of my current validation code:

```js
const schema = Joi.object({
  amount: Joi.number().required(),
});
```

This code only accepts numbers with a dot as the decimal separator, like `12.35`. However, I want to accept numbers with both dot and comma as the decimal separator, like `12.35` and `12,35`.

How can I modify my validation code to allow `Joi.number()` to accept decimal numbers with both dot and comma as separators?